# How to make WordPress navigation static

Tags: css, wordpress, static, navigation

I'm looking to make my navigation in WordPress static. By this I mean I wish for it to remain at the top of a user's browser regardless of how far down he/she scrolls. The effect I'm looking for is similar to one found at http://www.chevrolet.com/

Any advice or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the template code for your wordpress navigation
2. Check what class it uses
3. Modify the css for that class using

   .yourNavClass {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1000;
   }

There you have it!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the following should do it.

ref:
1. line 63 of main.css
2. line 203 of main.css

```
#container #mds-area-header {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
#mds-area-header .nav_second_level_1 {
    margin-top:0px;
}
```